# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/vrconfig.json'. Как решить проблему

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/vrconfig.json'. Как решить проблему

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотели сослаться на модуль в текущей папке, тогда путь должен быть `'./vrconfig.json'`, потому что `'/vrconfig.json'` ссылается на модуль в корне диска.